Why doesnt Lord punish maya for deluding the jivas?
Why doesnt God punish maya for deluding the souls? What is your opinion?
I am asking with a dvaita perspective..

No i am speaking about Maya shakti

Maya is an energy of the Lord (mama maya duratyaya) unlike the concept of good vs. evil in other cultures. Jiva desiring enjoyment separately from God is covered by Maya who covers the truth and creates delusion. Suggest reading the Gita where Krishna clearly describes how to overcome maya (Mamaiva hi prapadyante..). Quote ls from Gita 7. 14.

Jiva is not soul. Jiva is maya, struggles to find soul (atma)

Harihari ji Maya is Lord's energy why is it deluding jiva..why doesnt Lord simply remove maya from jiva?

@Harsh ji - The jiva's freewill to experience happiness independent of the paramatma is the cause for birth, rebirth, suffering and so-called happiness in the material world. This primal desire is then facilitated by maya through her influence. The Lord certainly orders maya to withdraw her influence from those souls who've surrendered to Him (sharanagati), obtained the special mercy of a pure devotee or the Lord Himself (kripa-siddhi), or attained perfection through practice (sadhana-siddhi). These souls return to the spiritual abode on quitting their body (yad gatva na nivartante..Gita 15.6)

when u say maya do u mean reality?

Maya is as eternal as Brahman. The only difference is Maya is not eternal on the realized, meaning maya subsides over the realized but continues as Maya for the rest. So the only entity that is Independent is Ishvara who is self-effulgent, self-governing and is the one who can rule over maya.
Source: ~ Vivekachudamani (Swami Prabhavananda, 1st chap)
So there is no GOD business in Sanatana Culture. One can interpret Ishvara or other swarupas as GOD, but that would cripple the very essence of this culture and its diverse vocabulary, such as, Ishavara, Avatara, Brahman, Amsha, Deva, Samisti and more. Same goes for "solus". So there is no maya deluding anyone. Its just that in the infinite possibility of Brahman, we are one such possibility, and as Sadhguru said we are having "individual experience" meaning we are NOT witnessing this creation as a whole, only in small parts.
"individual experience" Means, A jiva is nothing but an agitation or vibration of Brahman (one of infinite possibilities). This agitation within Brahman is to create a temporary state of “absence-of-consciousness-of-Brahman”, meaning Brahman (the infinite awareness) within itself creates a momentary agitation to temporarily mask the notion of the supreme consciousness, this temporary absence-of-consciousness-of-Brahman is called the Jiva (individual experience). Hence, Jiva is attributed to Shakti (agitation) and not to Consciousness, whereas Atman is attributed to Consciousness.
Hence, there is no "God punishing Maya". This notion comes from the Abrahamic culture of "God Punishing the Devil for corrupting humans for their souls". Following is the source link in case you want to get an idea of the vocabulary.
Source Link1

@Harsh I have added more content to this Answer
